# Extension that display articles/module based on visitors category choice

Tags: joomla, setcookie

Does anyone knows an extensions that will display Joomla! articles, like a category blog layout, based on first interaction visitors choice?

I don't want to stress the visitors and to make them create a user and then select the category of interest unless it's a must do.

I want to make them choose some category of interests (News, Fashion, etc.), set a cookie with those values in their browser and then display the latest articles from those categories and remember for, let's say 30 days, the choice for further visits.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question might be better asked at: https://joomla.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any extension to do this, but you could do it yourself easily enough. You could have a page to first check the cookie. If set, then you redirect to the category blog. If not, then this page has a form which collects the info and sets the cookie, and then redirects to the category blog. You could use Breezingforms for this, as it allows you to add post forms actions, so you can set your cookie.

Your category blog would have to be a custom component (I don't think you would get away with a template override of com_content here). You could copy com_content to create a new extension and then you would only need to read the cookie and adjust the categories displayed (instead of the component getting this info from the database). Everything else would be the same (if you have existing template overrides for com_content remember to copy them over).